# Too many textAnnotations result from google vision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I have try to request TEXT_DETECTION and 1 of maxResults, this is body json sample :

```
{
  "requests": [
    {

      "image": {
          "content": "",
          "source": {
              "gcsImageUri": "",
              "imageUri": "https://www.optumhealthfinancial.com/content/dam/optumhealthfinancial/Images/receipts.gif"
            }
        },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the result of `textAnnotations` has more than one record & more than 1MB size of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of [Text detection responses](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#text_detection_responses):

> A TEXT_DETECTION response includes the detected phrase, its bounding
>   box, and **individual words and their bounding boxes**

So you'll have bounding boxes for each word in your example image. Besides, from the definition of [TextAnnotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#TextAnnotation)

> TextAnnotation contains a structured representation of OCR extracted
>   text. The hierarchy of an OCR extracted text structure is like this:
>   **TextAnnotation -> Page -> Block -> Paragraph -> Word ->**

The size of your results are due the the quantity of information contained in you example image. `maxResults` is for cases where there can be more than one result (faceAnnotation, textAnnotations) as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageResponse). You are not getting multiple results, there's one result for each word of the detected paragraph.

If you want a smaller result, run the request using **DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION**:

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "image": 
      {
        "content": "",
        "source": 
        {
          "gcsImageUri": "",
          "imageUri": "https://www.optumhealthfinancial.com/content/dam/optumhealthfinancial/Images/receipts.gif"
        }
      },
      "features": 
      [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I mean, what the function of `maxResults` if I still get more than one result of textAnnotation?

Comment: maxResults is for cases where there can be more than one result (faceAnnotation, textAnnotations). Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageResponse). You are not getting multiple results, there's one result for each word of the detected paragraph. If you want a smaller result, run the request the way I show below

Comment: Run this, using **DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION**:                                 `{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "image": 
      {
        "content": "",
        "source": 
        {
          "gcsImageUri": "",
          "imageUri": "https://www.optumhealthfinancial.com/content/dam/optumhealthfinancial/Images/receipts.gif"
        }
      },
      "features": 
      [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

[maxResults](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature) doesn't apply to TEXT_DETECTION

> Maximum number of results of this type. Does not apply to TEXT_DETECTION, DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION, or CROP_HINTS.